# How to upgrade Bitcoin Core from 0.18 to 0.20 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, ubuntu

I've installed **Bitcoin Core** on **Ubuntu 18.04** (CLI). Now, the version 0.20 of Bitcoin Core is released and I want to upgrade my server to it, but it seems the new version is not included in PPA yet. May you help me to upgrade my Bitcoin Core server to 0.20 in a safe and correct way please?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I usually do it. Check the wget links in https://bitcoincore.org/bin

```
# Download Bitcoin Core packages for Ubuntu

wget https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.20.0/bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz

# check the checksum and fingerprint //optional
wget https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.20.0/SHA256SUMS.asc
wget https://bitcoin.org/laanwj-releases.asc
sha256sum --check SHA256SUMS.asc --ignore-missing
    >expected: xxx.tar.gz: OK
gpg --import ./laanwj-releases.asc
gpg --refresh-keys
gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.asc
    >expected: Good signature from "Wladimir J. van der Laan ..."

# extract, install and check versions of the binaries
tar -xvf bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
sudo install -m 0755 -o root -t /usr/local/bin bitcoin-0.20.0/bin/*
bitcoind --version
    >expected: Bitcoin Core version x0.20.0
```

Comment: When I run `sha256sum --check SHA256SUMS.asc --ignore-missing` I receive `bitcoin-0.20.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz: OK` and `sha256sum: WARNING: 20 lines are improperly formatted`

Comment: It's fine :) Formatting of 20 lines is improper to do sha256sum, from how I understand it, it's somewhat expected if you don't force the check sha256sum.

Comment: I'm getting different warnings while running your codes... `gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature! gpg:  There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.` , `gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found`

Comment: I think it's because it's still a key you've just downloaded from the internet. The warning says it can't confirm that this key is certified (legit). I don't know more secure way of checking validity if you're not into building the package yourself. And the only way for it to be false is if both sources would be spoofed.

Comment: Here is extended explanation: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/565/how-can-one-download-the-bitcoin-client-securely